# How to execute code in MSBuild after references are copied

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I need to perform code generation before a project builds, so the generated code is included in the build. For that I am using PreBuildEvent. The problem is when I need to use an assembly that is referenced by the project, and in PreBuildEvent it is not copied yet. Is there another event I can use? BTW, I'm using C# (csproj).

Comment: Would breaking it up into two builds be an option?  I've worked in code bases where generated code is built with one build process, and the resulting package is imported via Nuget into the solution that depends on it.  Granted it requires some set up, either a CICD pipeline, dumping the generated packages into a local Nuget repo, or something similar, but it does solve the chicken-egg problem.